# Advanced trigonometric identity verification

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have been practicing a lot of trigonometries recently. In fact my previous question was on trigonometry. I was practicing "verify the identity" and stumbled upon this question. I used "symbolab" to help me and I got "No steps".

So does it mean that they are not equal to each other? Because I thought that if it told me to verify that means that it's impossible that they won't be equal.

$$
\sin^4(2x)=\frac{3}{8}-\frac{1}{2}\cos(4x)+\frac{1}{8}\cos(8x)
$$

Comment: They are equal. What have you tried besides asking a piece of software?

Comment: @rogerl Umm, trying to solve this. I couldn't so I tried 'symbolab'. Then it didn't work so I surfed the internet and found no trig. close to this so I can at least get the gist. Then I asked a question on a forum where people help each other and not negatively criticise others without any help or advice.

Comment: @Khalid What the previous comment was asking for a detailed description of your attempt to solve the problem. SE requires this so the question doesn't sound like a copied homework problem and other users can follow from your train of thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula is correct. Using purely trigonometry, we can do
\begin{align}
\sin^4x&=(\sin^2x)^2=\left(\frac{1-\cos2x}{2}\right)^2=\frac{1}{4}(1-2\cos2x+\cos^22x)\nonumber\\
&=\frac{1}{4}(1-2\cos2x)+\frac{1}{8}(1+\cos 4x)=\frac{3}{8}-\frac{1}{2}\cos2x+\frac{1}{8}\cos4x.
\end{align}
Then replacing $x\mapsto 2x$ you get the formula. Using complex numbers, we can also do
\begin{align}
\sin^4x&=\left(\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}\right)^4=\frac{1}{16}(e^{4ix}-4e^{2ix}+6-4e^{-2ix}+e^{-4ix})\nonumber\\
&=\frac{3}{8}-\frac{1}{4}(e^{2ix}+e^{-2ix})+\frac{1}{16}(e^{4ix}+e^{-4ix})\\
&=\frac{3}{8}-\frac{1}{2}\cos2x+\frac{1}{8}\cos4x.
\end{align}
Both methods get the same formula.

Comment: Thank you @Zhuoran He, I think I will go with the first method :D. I haven't done anything similar to the second method yet.

Answer (score 0):

Verify the following identity:
$$sin^4(2x) = \frac{3}{8} - \frac{1}{2}cos(4x) + \frac{1}{8}cos(8x)$$
To keep the numbers a little nicer, I'm gonna multiply throughout by 8.
Then, substitute $cos(2\Theta)=1-2sin^2(\Theta)$ into both of the cosine expressions on the right, as shown:
$$8sin^4(2x)=3-4(1-2sin^2(2x)) + (1-2sin^2(4x))$$
Simplifying, we have
$$8sin^4(2x) = 8sin^2(2x) - 2sin^2(4x)$$
Substituting the pythagorean identity $sin^2(\Theta)=1-cos^2(\Theta)$ into $2sin^2(4x)$ yields
$$8sin^4(2x)=8sin^2(2x)-2(1-cos^2(4x))$$
We can then factor $1-cos^2(4x)$ into $(1+cos(4x))(1-cos(4x))$ and apply the double angle formula from above again:
$$8sin^4(2x)=8sin^2(2x)-2(1+(1-2sin^2(2x)))(1-(1-2sin^2(2x)))$$
Simplifying again, we have
$$8sin^4(2x)=8sin^2(2x)-(4sin^2(2x))(2-2sin^2(2x))$$
We can distribute $-4sin^2(2x)$ to find that $8sin^2(2x)$ and $-8sin^2(2x)$ cancel, leaving 
$$8sin^4(2x)=8sin^4(2x)$$
which is true for all $x \epsilon (-\infty, \infty)$.

Comment: but I kinda like @Zhuoran He 's method better....

Answer (score 0):

Set $y=2x$, so the identity you have to verify is
$$
\cos(4y)-4\cos(2y)+3=8\sin^4y
$$
We can work on the left-hand side, using $\cos(2t)=1-2\sin^2(t)$ and $\sin(2t)=2\sin(t)\cos(t)$. To begin with,
\begin{align}
\cos(4y)
&=1-2\sin^2(2y)\\
&=1-8\sin^2(y)\cos^2(y)\\
&=1-8\sin^2(y)\bigl(1-\sin^2(y)\bigr)\\
&=1-8\sin^2(y)+8\sin^4(y)
\end{align}
and therefore
\begin{align}
\cos(4y)-4\cos(2y)+3
&=1-8\sin^2(y)+8\sin^4(y)-4\bigl(1-2\sin^2(y)\bigr)+3\\
&=1-8\sin^2(y)+8\sin^4(y)-4+8\sin^2(y)+3\\
&=8\sin^4(y)
\end{align}